# Минимизация функции с интегралом python

Tags: python, численные-методы, интегральное-исчисление

Задача: нужно найти параметр tau0, решая уравнение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где все, кроме tau0 -- константы.

Самым удобным способом, мне кажется, является минимизация Нелдера-Мида, что я и сделал, перенеся правую часть уравнения в левую и осуществив поиск минимального значения полученной функции, коим должен являться 0:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize



# CaII 3933, 3968
l1, l2, W1, W2, f1, f2 = 3933.22, 3968.03, 0.052, 0.034, 0.708, 0.351

fij = l1*f1/(l2*f2)
f1 = lambda x, tau: 1 - np.exp(-tau**2.0*fij*np.exp(x**2.0))
f2 = lambda x, tau: 1 - np.exp(-tau**2.0*np.exp(x**2.0))

def func(tau):
    integral1 = quad(f1, -np.inf, np.inf, args=(tau,))
    integral2 = quad(f2, -np.inf, np.inf, args=(tau,))
    s = l1*integral1[0]/(l2*integral2[0]) - W1/W2
    return s


def chi2(pars):
    p = (0 - func(pars[0]))**2.0
    return p
    
pars = [1] 
#bnds = ((0, 20))
res = minimize(chi2, pars, method = 'Nelder-Mead')
print('tau = ', res.x[0])

print('\n func value at tau:', func(res.x[0]))
```

И все бы хорошо, но **при различных значениях констант** *результат* минимизации получается **одним и тем же**.

В чем может быть ошибка в коде?
Интегралы проверил, quad все считает.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, величина tau_0 должна входить в первой степени в это уравнение, число 2 означает индекс. Так что всегда разбираемся, что и что означает...
Нелдер-Мид все прекрасно считает для таких функций с интегралами.